# Proof of positivity of $~ x+\sqrt{x^2+1} ~$ of $~\operatorname{arsinh}(x)=\operatorname{arcsinh}(x)=\sinh^{-1}(x)= \ln \left( x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)$

Tags: inequality, logarithms, systems-of-equations, hypergeometric-function

Proof of positivity of $~ x+\sqrt{x^2+1}  ~$

I found this formula appears at $~ \operatorname{arsinh}(x)= \ln \left( x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)~$

So, of course this argument inside the natural log function should be positive.

I tried to prove the positivity using proof of contradiction.

$$ \color{fuchsia}{\begin{align}
&x+\sqrt{x^2+1} \leq 0
\\&\iff \sqrt{x^2+1} \leq -x
\\&\iff \underbrace{x^2+1 \geq x^2}_{~~\text{Able to be held}~~ }  
\end{align}}  $$

$$ \color{red}{\begin{align}
&x+\sqrt{x^2+1} >0 
\\&\iff \sqrt{x^2+1} >-x
\\&\iff \underbrace{x^2+1 < x^2}_{~~\text{Unable to be held}~~ }  
\end{align}}  $$

What is going on?

Comment: You can't square an inequality unless both sides are non-negative. And you don't have to go that way, instead, just use that $\,0 \le x + |x| \le x + \sqrt{x^2+1}\,$.

Comment: @dxiv That special rule of inequality is quite surprising for me.

Comment: That's not a special rule. Squaring an inequality follows from multiplying inequalities, which only holds between positives.

Comment: The inequality does not invert when you square. So the results should be exactly opposite. An inequality does invert if you multiply with a negative number, but that is not the case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake I made above my question-post is that I flipped the symbol of inequality even signs of both endpoints of inequality is different.

$$\begin{align}
\text{negative real value}<\text{positive real value}  
\end{align}$$

At this sitch, one can't flip $~ <~$  to $~ > ~$ as both terms are squared . I've completely missed it.

$$\begin{align}
&0\leq x+\left| x \right|= x + \sqrt{x^2} \leq x+ \sqrt{x^2+1}~~\text{for}~~x\in\mathbb{R}_{<0}\\
&\therefore~~0\leq x+ \sqrt{x^2+1}  
\end{align}$$

$~ \sqrt{x^2}\leq \sqrt{x^2+1} ~$ can be held since a root function is a  monotonous increasing function.